# Performing a nested filter/join

Tags: rethinkdb

I have 3 tables. `forums`, which have many `posts` which have many `comments`. I'd like to retrieve all `comments` from one particular `forum`. I know I can perform the following as separate queries:

```
var chosenForumID = "...";
var posts = /* get all posts where post.forumID === chosenForumID */;
var comments = /* get all comments where comment.postID is in 'posts' */;
```

though is it possible with one nested query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Naive Way**

You can actually do that in just one query by doing the following:

```
r.table('forums')
 .get(ID)
 .merge({
   'comments': r.table('posts').filter({ 'forumID': ID })('id').coerceTo('array')
      .do(function (postsIdsArray) {
        return r.table('comments').filter(function (row) {
           return postsIdsArray.contains(row('id'));
        })
      }).coerceTo('array')
 })('comments')
```

**Better Way**

If you're executing this operation a lot and you have the relationship on the child (child has a parent property pointing to the ID), then you should create a secondary index for `forumID` and `postID`.

```
// Create Indexes
r.table('posts').indexCreate('forumId')
r.table('comments').indexCreate('postId')
```

After creating them (you only have to create them once), you can then use the `getAll` term to make it an index operation.

```
r.table('forums')
 .get(1)
 .merge({
   'comments': r.table('posts').getAll(1, { index: 'forumId' })('id').coerceTo('array')
      .do(function (postsIdsArray) {
        return r.table('comments').getAll(r.args(postsIdsArray), { index: 'postId' }).coerceTo('array')
      })
 })('comments')
```

Secondary indexes make this operation faster.